# Debugging No Longer Works for DX CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, plugin-bug

Lately in VS Code, my custom DX CLI plugin is no longer stopping when using the `--dev-suspend` flag, and the commands just run like normal. Breakpoints are no longer being hit when using the flag.

Output of `node --version`: v12.21.0

Output of `code --version`: 1.56.2
054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335
x64

Output of `sfdx --version`: sfdx-cli/7.110.0 win32-x64 node-v14.17.3

Here is what my `launch.json` file configuration looks like:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "SFDX CLI Debugger",
      "address": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 9229,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "preLaunchTask": "Compile",
      "outFiles": ["{workspaceFolder}/**.js", "!**/node_modules/**"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Run All Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": ["--inspect", "--no-timeouts", "--colors", "test/**/*.test.ts"],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "SFDX_ENV": "development"
      },
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "preLaunchTask": "Compile"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Run Current Test",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": ["--inspect", "--no-timeouts", "--colors", "${file}"],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "SFDX_ENV": "development"
      },
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "preLaunchTask": "Compile"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Compile",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "command": "yarn",
      "type": "shell",
      "presentation": {
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "dedicated"
      },
      "args": ["run", "prepack"],
      "isBackground": false,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "fileLocation": "relative",
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^(.*\\.ts):(\\d*):(\\d*)(\\s*-\\s*)(error|warning|info)\\s*(TS\\d*):\\s*(.*)$",
          "file": 1,
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "severity": 5,
          "code": 6,
          "message": 7
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Lint",
      "command": "yarn",
      "type": "shell",
      "presentation": {
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "dedicated"
      },
      "args": ["run", "lint"],
      "isBackground": false,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "fileLocation": "relative",
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^(ERROR|WARNING|INFO):\\s*(.*\\.ts):(\\d*):(\\d*)(\\s*-\\s*)(.*)$",
          "file": 2,
          "line": 3,
          "column": 4,
          "severity": 1,
          "message": 6
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In my settings.json in VS Code, I have tried toggling `"debug.javascript.usePreview":` back and forth between `true` and `false` but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Has anyone run across similar issues with the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was the AutoAttach feature under **File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > JavaScript Debugger > Auto Attach Filter**. Setting it to **smart** didn't seem to work, but once set to **always** everything worked again.